# Android NFC is Not Working Properly

Tags: android, nfc

I am trying to read Credit Cards by NFC. I tried it on 10 different devices (all of them Samsung Note 3 and Android version 5.0). Even some of them works fine others are not. But some other NFC Reader applications are working properly on all of them. I'm using the same apk, devices and Android versions on my tests. So that I don't know why this issue happens. Is there any efficient way to catch NFC actions ? I'm using the code below to catch NFC actions:

NFCReadActivity - onCreate:

```
nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
            nfcPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                    new Intent(this, this.getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);

            //endregion

            //region NFC Control
            if (nfcAdapter == null) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "NFC not supported..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            } else if (!nfcAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "NFC is closed..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
            }
            //endregion


            onNewIntent(getIntent());
```

NFCReadActivity - onNewIntent :

```
 @Override    
    void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
                if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
                    Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
                    setCardInfosFromNFC(tag);
                } else if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
                    Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
                    setCardInfosFromNFC(tag);
                } else if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
                    // In case we would still use the Tech Discovered Intent
                    Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
                    String[] techList = tag.getTechList();
                    String searchedTech = Ndef.class.getName();

                    for (String tech : techList) {
                        if (searchedTech.equals(tech)) {
                            setCardInfosFromNFC(tag);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }


            }
```

Manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true" />

<activity
            android:name=".Activity.ReadNFCActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"/>
                <meta-data android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
```

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: What code do you have in `onResume()` (or more specifically, where and how do you use `nfcPendingIntent`)? What exactly happens in those cases where your app "does not work"?

Comment: I found the problem. When I disable SHealth app, my app is working properly. Can I set priority to my app in any case ?

Comment: Again, what code do you have in `onResume()` (or more specifically, where and how do you use `nfcPendingIntent`)? Also, do you want your activity to be opend by scanning the card or do you just want to read the card while your activity is already open/in the foreground?